# Find common elements in N sorted arrays with no extra space

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given N arrays with sizeof N, and they are all sorted, if it does not allow you to use extra space, how will find their common datas efficiently or with less time complexity?

For ex:

```
 1. 10 160 200 500 500
 2. 4 150 160 170 500
 3. 2 160 200 202 203
 4. 3 150 155 160 300
 5. 3 150 155 160 301
```

This is an interview question, I found some questions which were similar but they didn't include the extra conditions of input being sorted or not being able to use extra memory.

I couldn't think of any solution less than O(n^2 lg n) complexity. In that case, I'd prefer to go with the simplest solution which gives me this complexity, which is:

```
  not_found_flag = false

  for each element 'v' in row-1
       for each row 'i' in the remaining set
           perform binary search for 'v' in 'i'
           if 'v' not found in row 'i'
                 not_found_flag = true
                 break
       if not not_found_flag 
           print element 'v' as it is one of the common element
```

We could improve this by comparing the min and max of each row and decide based on that whether it is possible for a number 'num' to fall between 'min_num' and 'max_num' of that row.

Binary search -> O(log n)
For searching 1 num in n-1 rows : O(nlogn)
Binary search for each number in first row : O(n2logn)

I selected first row, we can pick any row and if a no element of the row picked is found in any of the (N-1) rows then we don't really have common data.

Comment: you need 'some' extra space to store the (possible) common elements...

Comment: @MitchWheat. Please look at the pseudo code above. If we're good with just printing the common elements, do we really need extra storage?

Comment: Are you really saving any thing by binary search.. since you need to find all common elements, why dont you just scan the sorted array and be done in O(n)

Comment: @smk. There are 'N' different arrays and each of them is independently sorted. I've edited the question with example. We can't find common elements in O(n) by scanning 'N' arrays. It's more like a NXN square matrix where each row is individually sorted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems this can be done in `O(n^2)`; i.e., just looking at each element once. Note that if an element is common to all the arrays then it must exist in any one of them. Also for purposes of illustration (and since you used the for loop above) I will assume we can keep an index for each of the arrays, but I'll talk about how to get around this later.

Let's call the arrays `A_1` through `A_N`, and use indices starting at 1. Pseudocode:

```
# Initial index values set to first element of each array
for i = 1 to N:
  x_i = 1 

for x_1 = 1 to N:
  val = A_1[x_1] 
  print_val = true
  for i = 2 to N:
    while A_i[x_i] < val:
      x_i = x_i + 1
    if A_i[x_i] != val:
      print_val = false
  if print_val:
    print val
```

**Explanation of algorithm.** We use the first array (or any arbitrary array) as the reference algorithm, and iterate through all the other arrays in parallel (kind of like the merge step of a merge sort, except with N arrays.) Every value of the reference array that is common to all the arrays must be present in all the other arrays. So for each other array (since they are sorted), we increase the index `x_i` until the value at that index `A_i[x_i]` is at least the value we are looking for (we don't care about lesser values; they can't be common.) We can do this since the arrays are sorted and thus monotonically nondecreasing. If all the arrays had this value, then we print it, otherwise we increment `x_1` in the reference array and keep going. We have to do this even if we don't print the value.

By the end, we've printed all the values that are common to all the arrays, while only having examined each element once.

**Getting around the extra storage requirement.** There are many ways to do this, but I think the easiest way would be to check the first element of each array and take the max as the reference array `A_1`. If they are all the same, print that value, and then store the indices `x_2 ... x_N` as the first element of each array itself.

Java implementation (for brevity, without the extra hack), using your example input:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] a = {
            { 10, 160, 200, 500, 500, },
            { 4, 150, 160, 170, 500, },
            { 2, 160, 200, 202, 203, },
            { 3, 150, 155, 160, 300 },
            { 3, 150, 155, 160, 301 } };

    int n = a.length;
    int[] x = new int[n];

    for( ; x[0] < n; x[0]++ ) {
        int val = a[0][x[0]]; 
        boolean print = true;
        for( int i = 1; i < n; i++ ) {
            while (a[i][x[i]] < val && x[i] < n-1) x[i]++;              
            if (a[i][x[i]] != val) print = false;               
        }   
        if (print) System.out.println(val);
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
160
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution in python `O(n^2)`, uses no extra space but destroys the lists:

```
def find_common(lists):
    num_lists = len(lists)
    first_list = lists[0]
    for j in first_list[::-1]:
        common_found = True
        for i in range(1,num_lists):
            curr_list = lists[i]
            while curr_list[len(curr_list)-1] > j:
                curr_list.pop()
            if curr_list[len(curr_list)-1] != j:
                common_found = False
                break
        if common_found:
            return j
```

Answer (score 1):

An O(n^2) (Python) version that doesn't use extra storage, but modify the original array. Allows to store the common elements without printing them:

```
data = [
    [10, 160, 200, 500, 500],
    [4, 150, 160, 170, 500],
    [2, 160, 200, 202, 203],
    [3, 150, 155, 160, 300],
    [3, 150, 155, 160, 301],
]

for k in xrange(len(data)-1):
    A, B = data[k], data[k+1]
    i, j, x = 0, 0, None

    while i<len(A) or j<len(B):
        while i<len(A) and (j>=len(B) or A[i] < B[j]):
            A[i] = x
            i += 1

        while j<len(B) and (i>=len(A) or B[j] < A[i]):
            B[j] = x
            j += 1

        if i<len(A) and j<len(B):
            x = A[i]
            i += 1
            j += 1

print data[-1]
```

What I'm doing is basically get every array in the data and comparing with it's next, element by element, removing those that are not common.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Java implementation

```
public static Integer[] commonElementsInNSortedArrays(int[][] arrays) {
    int baseIndex = 0, currentIndex = 0, totalMatchFound= 0;
    int[] indices = new int[arrays.length - 1];
    boolean smallestArrayTraversed = false;
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (!smallestArrayTraversed && baseIndex < arrays[0].length) {
        totalMatchFound = 0;
        for (int array = 1; array < arrays.length; array++) {
            currentIndex = indices[array - 1];
            while (currentIndex < arrays[array].length && arrays[array][currentIndex] < arrays[0][baseIndex]) {
                currentIndex ++;                    
            }

            if (currentIndex < arrays[array].length) {
                if (arrays[array][currentIndex] == arrays[0][baseIndex]) {
                    totalMatchFound++;
                }
            } else {
                smallestArrayTraversed = true;
            }
            indices[array - 1] = currentIndex;
        }
        if (totalMatchFound == arrays.length - 1) {
            result.add(arrays[0][baseIndex]);
        }
        baseIndex++;
    }

    return result.toArray(new Integer[0]);
}
```

Here is the Unit Tests

```
@Test
public void commonElementsInNSortedArrayTest() {
    int arr[][] = { {1, 5, 10, 20, 40, 80},
                    {6, 7, 20, 80, 100},
                    {3, 4, 15, 20, 30, 70, 80, 120}
                   };

    Integer result[] = ArrayUtils.commonElementsInNSortedArrays(arr);
    assertThat(result, equalTo(new Integer[]{20, 80}));

    arr = new int[][]{
            {23, 34, 67, 89, 123, 566, 1000},
            {11, 22, 23, 24,33, 37, 185, 566, 987, 1223, 1234},
            {23, 43, 67, 98, 566, 678},
            {1, 4, 5, 23, 34, 76, 87, 132, 566, 665},
            {1, 2, 3, 23, 24, 344, 566}
          };

    result = ArrayUtils.commonElementsInNSortedArrays(arr);
    assertThat(result, equalTo(new Integer[]{23, 566}));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Swift solution makes a copy of the original but could be modified to take an `inout` parameter so that it takes no additional space. I left it as a copy because I think it is better to not modify the original since it deletes elements. It is  possible to not remove elements by keeping indices, but this algorithm removes elements to keep track of where it is. This is a functional approach, and may not be super efficient but works. Since it is functional less conditional logic is necessary. I posted it because I thought it might be a different approach which might be interesting to others, and maybe others can figure out ways of making it more efficient.

```
func findCommonInSortedArrays(arr: [[Int]]) -> [Int] {
    var copy = arr
    var result: [Int] = []

    while (true) {

        // get first elements
        let m = copy.indices.compactMap { copy[$0].first }

        // find max value of those elements.
        let mm = m.reduce (0) { max($0, $1) }

        // find the value in other arrays or nil
        let ii = copy.indices.map { copy[$0].firstIndex { $0 == mm } }

        // if nil present in of one of the arrays found, return result
        if (ii.map { $0 }).count != (ii.compactMap { $0 }.count) { return result }

        // remove elements that don't match target value.
        copy.indices.map { copy[$0].removeFirst( ii[$0] ?? 0 ) }

        // add to list of matching values.
        result += [mm]

        // remove the matched element from all arrays
        copy.indices.forEach { copy[$0].removeFirst() }
    }
}

findCommonInSortedArrays(arr: [[9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 29],
                         [3, 5, 9, 10, 13, 14],
                         [3, 9, 10, 14]]
)

findCommonInSortedArrays(arr: [[],
                         [],
                         []]
)

findCommonInSortedArrays(arr: [[9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 29],
                         [3, 5, 9, 10, 13, 14],
                         [3, 9, 10, 14],
                         [9, 10, 29]]
)

findCommonInSortedArrays(arr: [[9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 29],
                               [3, 5, 9, 10, 13, 14],
                               [3, 9, 10, 14],
                               [9, 10, 29]]
)
```